# Getting the Installation Folder of Running Application using C#

Tags: c#, .net

There were several other similar posts, but I could not pinpoint one that relates entirely to my issue.

Simply put, say my application exe file is located in `C:\MyApp\run.exe`,

how can I find the programatically find the path `C:\MyApp`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two of the answers given are correct, but rely on using Windows Forms. If that is not your cup of tea, there are alternatives.

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName)
```

and also

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase)
```

Answer (score 8):

```
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
```

UPDATE:

For a WPF application you could use the following:

```
using System.Reflection;

string appPath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
```

Comment: @Shamim Hafiz: I've updated my answer with a WPF compatible version. You could also go with Matthew Ferreira's way.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Environment.CurrentDirectory` - if your program hasn't manipulated this value for any reason, it should show you the path from which the program was run.